# Let $B$ be a countable set and let $f$ be a surjective function ($f:A\to B$), then $A$ is also countable

Tags: real-analysis, functions, examples-counterexamples

Question: Given a countable set $B$ and a function $f:A\to B$ which is surjective, then $A$ is also countable.

I think it's a false affirmation, but I have no idea of a counter example I can use here.

I basically know that: every subset $X \subseteq N$ is a countable set. And the corollary: given a countable set $A$ and a function $f:A\to B$ which is surjective on $B$, then $B$ is also countable.

Comment: $x\mapsto\lfloor x\rfloor$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb N$ defined as

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
x \text{ if } x \in \Bbb N\\
1 \text{ if } x \not\in \Bbb N
\end{cases}$$

Edit:
I remembered that there's no concensus on the use of "countable". I've assumed it meant "countable infinite", that is, the same size of $\Bbb N$. But it's also used to denote "finite or of the size of $\Bbb N$", in which case a simpler example would be $f:\Bbb R \to \{0\}$ given by $f(x)=0$ for all $x$.

Comment: thank you so much!

Comment: Set-theorists usually take "countable" to mean "finite or countably infinite" so that in English, "uncountable" and "not countable" mean the same thing.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet As I said, there's no concensus. Terence Tao, for example, defines "countable” as "having the same cardinality of $\Bbb N$" and uses "at most countable" to include finite sets.

Comment: @jjagmath. It's like the debate over whether 0 is a natural number.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the function $f: \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\}$ given by $f(x) = \lceil |x| \rceil$.  This is clearly a well defined function since if $x_1=x_2$, then $|x_1|=|x_2|$ and thus $\lceil |x_1| \rceil = \lceil |x_2| \rceil$.

Further, given any $y \in \mathbb{N}$, we can surely find $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\lceil |x| \rceil = y$.  Namely, $x=y-0.5$. If $y=0$, then $f(0)=0$.  Hence $f$ is surjective.

However, $\mathbb{R}$ isn't countable.

Comment: thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

Simple counter:

f: R--->{x} be a function such that
f(y) = x for all y in R

Co domain is a singleton set ,so it is countable.

But domain is set of all real numbers which is uncountable.